# The attribute 'cachable' is not allowed. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, installation, localhost

I am facing the error in Magento **Localhost** which is

> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /var/www/html/magento/app/code/Mb/Customizations/etc/frontend/events.xml:
>   Element 'event', attribute 'cachable': The attribute 'cachable' is not allowed.
>   Line: 9

In the image you can see the error 
[image]

So after That I tried to remove **cacheable** from the core class
`magento/app/code/Mb/Customizations/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="cust_productCanonical" instance="Mb\Customizations\Observer\ProductCanonical"/>
    </event>

    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index" cachable="false">
        <observer name="checkcout_page_pre" instance="Mb\Customizations\Observer\Preloadtab" />
    </event>
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_index_index" cachable="false">
        <observer name="checkcout_page_post" instance="Mb\Customizations\Observer\Loadtab" />
    </event>

</config>
```

but after removing the `casheable` from the above `xml` file it gives me some else error

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /var/www/html/magento/app/code/TM/Crm/etc/frontend/events.xml:
>   Element 'config': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( event ).
>   Line: 2

[image]

`magento/app/code/TM/Crm/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

<!--     <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="tm_crm_checkout_onepage_controller_success_action" instance="TM\Crm\Observer\Crm" />
    </event> -->

</config>
```

So how can I remove this error and what is the problem in the above `xml` file. Thanks

Comment: `cachable="false"` should only be used for blocks not for events. here is the full docs from magento https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/public-content.html

Comment: ok fine but when I remove the `cachable` then it give me another error
`1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /var/www/html/magento/app/code/TM/Crm/etc/frontend/events.xml: Element 'config': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( event ). Line: 2`

Comment: Cachable? Cashable? Cacheable? Man, that typo variations can kill you :) My bet is you may have some white space in that XML between config and event after cleaning the wrong references

Comment: Please post your XML? `magento/app/code/TM/Crm/etc/frontend/events.xml`

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Sir question updated kindly check it

Comment: Empty `events.xml` doesn't allow.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh so Sir how to solve this?

Comment: You should remove `magento/app/code/TM/Crm/etc/frontend/events.xml`

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh sir now it gives me 
`Exception #0 (Zend_Uri_Exception): Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted` error

Answer (score 1):

Just make the xml look like this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="cust_productCanonical" instance="Mb\Customizations\Observer\ProductCanonical"/>
    </event>
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_index_index">
        <observer name="checkcout_page_pre" instance="Mb\Customizations\Observer\Preloadtab" />
    </event>
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_index_index">
        <observer name="checkcout_page_post" instance="Mb\Customizations\Observer\Loadtab" />
    </event>
</config>
```

If you don't have any event tags in your file, remove the file completely. You cannot have an empty file.

Comment: Sir I tried this but it gives me an error
`Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid XML in file /var/www/html/magento/app/code/TM/Crm/etc/frontend/events.xml:
Element 'config': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( event )`

Comment: Please clear cache after changes suggested by Marius .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
        <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
            <observer name="cust_productCanonical" instance="Mb\Customizations\Observer\ProductCanonical"/>
        </event>
    </config>
```

Make sure your XML is UTF-8 formatted, Then do cache flush and try it.